# 与えられたリストがすべて整数であることを判定する方法

Tags: python, python3

与えられた変数がリストで、リスト内の要素がすべて整数であることを判定したいです。

isinstanceでtype判定し、数値以外が混在し、sumが失敗すればTypeError例外。sumが成功し、結果がint型であれば、整数だと判断します。1.0などは意図的にfloatを含めたと判断してエラーとしています。
作成したソースコードは、正しく動作しております。

もっと簡便に判定する方法はないでしょうか？

### ソースコード

```py
def check(int_list:list):
  if isinstance(int_list,list):
    try:
      s = sum(int_list)
      if not isinstance(s, int):
         raise Exception('整数のリストではありません。')
    except TypeError:
      raise Exception('整数のリストではありません。')
  else:
    raise Exception('リストではありません。')

  return int_list
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

本家SOに、ご質問に合致する[回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13252348)がありました。
組み込み関数の[all](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#all)を使って `all({判定} for x in list)` のように判定することで、リストの全項目が判定条件を満たすかチェックすることができます。

```
int_list = [1,2,3]
is_all_int = all(isinstance(x, int) for x in int_list)
print(is_all_int) # True

float_list = [1,2,3, 4.5]
is_all_int = all(isinstance(x, int) for x in float_list)
print(is_all_int) # False

obj_list = [1,2,3, "4"]
is_all_int = all(isinstance(x, int) for x in obj_list)
print(is_all_int) # False
```

Comment: なるほどallを使うんですね。